# Passing value from test class to in vocable method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, compile-error

I have create a invocable method for call from the flow. Now I want to create a test class.

Apex Class:

```
public static void Fee(List<Id> ids){
        sample__c s= [select id from sample__c  where id =: ids limit 1]; 
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class samp_Test {
    sample__c samp = new sample__c();
        samp .Name='123 test street';
    insert samp ;
Test.StartTest(); 
        FeeCalc tif=new FeeCalc();
        tif.Fee(Ids);     

        Test.StopTest();
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Fee() from the type FeeCalc

Answer (score 2):

If you define a method as `static`, then call it statically:

**Static Method Definition**

```
public static void myStaticMethod() { }
```

**Static Method Call**

```
MyClass.myStaticMethod();
```

---

If you define an instance method, then call it from an instance:

**Instance Method Definition**

```
public void myInstanceMethod() { }
```

**Instance Method Call**

```
new MyClass().myInstanceMethod();
```

---

You are trying to call a static method from an instance, which is not allowed.

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
instance.myStaticMethod(); // not allowed
```